# Detecting `std::shared_ptr` malfunction

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am starting to write a simple SQLite wrapper.

One of the functions is

```
  template <typename... t_fields>
  void exec(const char *p_sql, t_fields &&... p_bindings) {
    sqlite3_stmt *_stmt{nullptr};
    int _rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_sqlite, p_sql, -1, &_stmt, NULL);
    if (_rc != SQLITE_OK) {
      throw std::runtime_error(sqlite3_errmsg(m_sqlite));
    }

    binder(_stmt, 1, std::forward<t_fields>(p_bindings)...);

    _rc = sqlite3_step(_stmt);
    if (_rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
      throw std::runtime_error(sqlite3_errmsg(m_sqlite));
    }
  }
```

Where `binder` is (first version)

```
template <typename t_field>
void binder(sqlite3_stmt *p_stmt, field_index p_index, t_field &&p_field) {
  if constexpr (type_traits::is_smart_ptr_v<t_field>) {
    binder<typename t_field::element_type>(p_stmt, p_index, *p_field);
    return;
  }
  if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<t_field>) {
    sqlite3_bind_int(p_stmt, p_index, std::forward<t_field>(p_field));
    return;
  }
  if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<t_field>) {
    sqlite3_bind_double(p_stmt, p_index, std::forward<t_field>(p_field));
    return;
  }
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<t_field, std::string>) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(p_stmt, p_index, p_field.c_str(), p_field.size(),
                      SQLITE_STATIC);
    return;
  }
  if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<t_field>) {
    binder<typename t_field::element_type>(p_stmt, p_index, *p_field);
    return;
  }
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<t_field, blob>) {
    sqlite3_bind_blob(p_stmt, p_index, (void *)(&(p_field[0])), p_field.size(),
                      SQLITE_STATIC);
    return;
  }
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<t_field, const char *>) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(p_stmt, p_index, p_field, std::strlen(p_field),
                      SQLITE_STATIC);
    return;
  }
  {
    std::stringstream _stream;
    _stream << p_field;
    const std::string &_str = _stream.str().c_str();
    sqlite3_bind_text(p_stmt, p_index, _str.c_str(), _str.size(),
                      SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  }
}

template <typename t_field, typename... t_fields>
void binder(sqlite3_stmt *p_stmt, field_index p_index, t_field &&p_field,
            t_fields &&... p_fields) {
  binder<t_field>(p_stmt, p_index, std::forward<t_field>(p_field));
  binder<t_fields...>(p_stmt, p_index + 1, std::forward<t_fields>(p_fields)...);
}
```

And `is_smart_ptr_v` is

```
template <typename t> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};

template <typename t>
struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<t>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename t> constexpr bool is_shared_ptr_v = is_shared_ptr<t>::value;

template <typename t> struct is_unique_ptr {
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename t> struct is_unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<t>> {
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename t> constexpr bool is_unique_ptr_v = is_unique_ptr<t>::value;

template <typename t>
using is_smart_ptr = std::conditional_t<
    is_shared_ptr_v<t>, std::true_type,
    std::conditional_t<is_unique_ptr_v<t>, std::true_type, std::false_type>>;

template <typename T> constexpr bool is_smart_ptr_v = is_smart_ptr<T>::value;
```

An example:

```
      auto _p{std::make_shared<std::string>("bla")};

      exec(R"(insert into data (id, t, i, f) values (?, ?, ?, ?))", 1, _p, 421, 3.14);
```

*The problem* is that `if constexpr (type_traits::is_smart_ptr_v<t_field>)` is not used when the shared pointer `_p` is passed to `binder`, but the code falls into `else` instead, and the address of `_p` is used in `sqlite3_bind_text`.

This is awkward because I use `is_smart_ptr_v` in another situation, also with `shared_ptr<string>` and it works fine.

Comment: I'm guessing `t_field` is `std::shared_ptr<std::string>&`, so you want `type_traits::is_smart_ptr_v<std::decay_t<t_field>>`

Comment: Unrelated simplification: `is_smart_ptr = std::conditional_t<is_shared_ptr_v<t>||is_unique_ptr_v<t>, std::true_type, std::false_type>;`

Comment: Artyer, that worked! 

Ted, it is really simpler this way.

Comment: @canellas Yes, it removes one `conditional_t` and makes it a lot clearer that you want `true_type` if it's a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` and `false_type` otherwise.